# How Do I Get RouteData Values from a Web Service in .Net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, web-services, routes, query-string, routedata

I am trying to extract an id number from a URL using a web service so that it can be used as a parameter for a where clause in a select statement that produces data from a database based on the id number of a record. That data will then be passed back to the page to populate an element in a jQuery modal popup widow.

Everything works fine with a static id number (ex: `string postid = "120"`), but I don't know how to get the id number from the URL. I'm using Routing in .Net 4 and the method for accessing Routing in pages does not work in a web service. In pages I just do stuff like `var id =  RouteData.Values["id"];` and that gets the id, but when i did it in a web service I got an error:

> CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property `'System.Web.Routing.RouteData.Values.get'`

Summary:

I have web service accessed form a details page where I want to get `RouteData` for the page making the request. I want to do this just as easily as I can on a page using `RouteData.Values` which is just as easy as the now the obsolete `Request.Querystring`.

---

Now I am more confused because although I could easily add a new route for the web service I don't know I would call that using jQuery Ajax because of the webservice.asmx/webmethod syntax.

Right now I have URL: "../webservices/googlemaps.asmx/GetGoogleMap" in my jQuery Ajax, but that is not a real URL. It only exists in jQuery somewhere and the way to call the service using just JavaScript is no a real URL either, its `webservice.webmethod()` which in this case would be `googlemaps.GetGoogleMap()`.

I will try registering a route for `webservices/googlemaps.asmx/GetGoogleMap/postid`, but I doubt it will work because `GetGoogleMap` is not a directory or a `querystring`.

Comment: YOu have control of the webservice? Can you provide some example urls of the service, as well as the declaration for them?

Comment: To format your code properly: Select *every line* of the code, then press `ctrl-K` or the `{}` button on the toolbar

Answer (score 7):

Get current http request and use [RequestContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.requestcontext.aspx) property to get request context - it has current [routing data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.requestcontext.routedata.aspx). For example,

```
var id = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
```

In case of WCF based web service, make sure that service is participating in ASP.NET pipeline (see [ASP.NET Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx))

**EDIT**: Sorry for misleading answer - the above will not work unless web service url is registered in routing engine. However, it may not solve your issue of retrieving the id - what kind of service implementation are you using? Are you making a GET request or POST request? Typically, web service handler (asmx) or WCF pipeline should convert GET/POST parameters to method parameters. Post your web service code and how you invoke it.

Comment: @IAmLearnings, see my edit. Please post your web service code and how you invoke it (by editing the question)!